# colon after Appendix name

Tags: punctuation, appendices

I am trying to solve a simple problem but have been unable to find a answer on this forum. My question is -- how can I put a colon after the appendix name? I feel that it should be pretty simple but the answers I found on this forum mostly relate to listing the appendix with a colon in ToC; I want that colon after the appendix name in the main body (I have no ToC).

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Here is some text ... 

\begin{appendices}
\section{A simple model} \label{app:model}

We present a simple model ...

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do that with the `\apptocmd` command, from `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\appendices}{\apptocmd{\thesection}{: }{}{}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Here is some text ...

\begin{appendices}
\section{A simple model} \label{app:model}

We present a simple model ...

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Added:**
To avoid side effects, you either redefine the `appendices` environment to add a colon in the right place – a bit long in my opinion. Or give up the `title` option of `appendix`  and add it yourself, with `etoolbox` and `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{etoolbox, chngcntr}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
 \titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large}{\appendixname~\thesection:}{0.5em}{}%
 \titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}%
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Here is some text ...

\begin{appendices}%
\section{A simple model} \label{app:model}
We present a simple model ...
\begin{equation}
    a = b
\end{equation}
\subsection{A still simpler model}
Blah blah
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution unfortunately leaves the `\quad` spacing intact (as seen in your example) and messes up subappendix numbering like this: `A.1` -> `A:.1`.

Comment: If using this method, the colon also is included if using \ref{app:model} in the text.

Comment: However, the problem can be circumvent by using "\hyperref[app:model]{A}". This is better solution since the colon is included also in the Table on Concents.

Comment: Another problem with this was that I had change the equation/figure/table numbering to \renewcommand{\theequation}{A\arabic{equation}} .. etc. Otherwise, nice solution.

Comment: @np8: I've added another solution to avoid any (?) side effects.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't tied to the `appendix` package, you can solve your problem in the following way:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format@#1\endcsname
    \csname format@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad % the default
  \fi
}
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \def\format@section{Appendix \thesection: }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Here is some text ... 

\appendix
\section{A simple model} \label{app:model}

We present a simple model ...


\end{document}
```

With the `appendix` package it's even easier, but a trick with `\patchcmd` is needed:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\appendices}{\quad}{: }{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Here is some text ... 

\begin{appendices}
\section{A simple model} \label{app:model}

We present a simple model ...
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Both codes give the same output, namely

[image]

However, subsections will print like

> **A.1  Title**

with the former method and

> **A.1: Title**

with the latter.

Comment: Thank you, egreg! The latter (with \patchcmd) works nicely.

Comment: The solution for the `appendix` package unfortunately does not work for the titles in the table of contents (I didn't test the other one).