# Appendix Numbering Format: Dash instead of Dot after (alphabetic) number of appendix

Tags: formatting, numbering, titlesec

How can I change the dot after appendix's numbering (A.) to dash (A -)?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{6,0,111}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,125,0}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.png}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centering ÍNDICE}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\titlecontents{section}[0em]{\medskip\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[0em]{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{paragraph}[0em]{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subparagraph}[0em]{\smallskip\itshape}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

\usepackage{units}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0mm}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{5mm}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0mm}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0mm}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{txfonts}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\footnotesize\thepage}%
\makeatother

\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
%\titlelabel{\theparagraph.\quad}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalsize}{\theparagraph.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[hang]{\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubparagraph.}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
    \appendix
    \section{INTRODUCTION TO DYNAMICS}

    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201323/colon-after-appendix-name

Comment: @jarauh - Not really a duplicate, as the OP is loading the `titlesec` package and is using that package's `\titlelabel` macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could insert the instruction

```
\titlelabel{\thetitle\ - }
```

immediately after `\appendix`.

If you want an en-dash instead of a simple dash, the instruction should be

```
\titlelabel{\thetitle\ -- }
```